# Mysql Type Casting in Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns `meta_key` and `meta_value`. Both of them are `varchar` now for `meta_key` `_price` the meta_value is a number like 10.0, 20.0 etc. I am trying to update this value to a higher number (percentage increase in price). I am trying to cast `meta_value` as integer but it is not working.

Here is what I am trying:

```
update wp_postmeta set CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED)=meta_value+meta_value*(0.60) 
where meta_key='_price'
```

But it gives this error:

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED)=CAST'

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left-side assignment part of [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement specifies column to update, not the value. You should use `CAST()` on right side of assignment operation.

```
UPDATE
    wp_postmeta
SET 
    meta_value = CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED) * 1.60 
WHERE
    meta_key = '_price';
```

Quote from [*manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

> The **SET** clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they
>   should be given.

Comment: +1 Also I would change `meta_value+meta_value*(0.60)`  to `meta_value*(1.60)`

Comment: @valex OP wants to increase value > `I am trying to update this value to a higher number (percentage increase in price).`

Comment: Sure but `X+X*0.60 = X*1.60`

Comment: @valex yeah... Missed leading `1` digit - just thouht, that you suggesting to lower the value. Now, I see, that you are right. Updated.